# An rcu_preempt detected stall on Embedded Linux bootup due to USB device tree?

Tags: boot, device-tree

Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve (or at least debug) this rcu_preempt problem I'm experiencing at bootup as shown in the log info below?

I *think* the problem is related to the device tree configuration of "USB1" (the second USB port) but I'm not sure what since the first USB port "USB0" does not have this problem and the device tree is defined identically for both ports.

Here's the logging at bootup:

```
[    0.932884] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.938388] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.946166] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: hcc params 0x0238f625 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000002010810
[    0.955602] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: irq 36, io mem 0xfe200000
[    0.961677] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.967187] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.974856] xhci-hcd xhci-hcd.1.auto: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.981927] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.985712] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.990289] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.994137] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    4.020674] Freeing initrd memory: 72488K
[   21.999957] rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
[   22.006039] rcu:     2-...0: (0 ticks this GP) idle=873/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=89/89 fqs=2626
[   22.014902]  (detected by 3, t=5255 jiffies, g=-1059, q=16380 ncpus=4)
[   22.021421] Task dump for CPU 2:
[   22.024633] task:kworker/u8:2    state:R  running task     stack:    0 pid:   51 ppid:     2 flags:0x0000000a
[   22.034548] Workqueue: events_unbound deferred_probe_work_func
[   22.040380] Call trace:
[   22.042810]  __switch_to+0x100/0x1b0
[   22.046378]  of_get_next_child+0x40/0x78
[   22.050293]  of_platform_populate+0x70/0x130
[   22.054555]  dwc3_xlnx_probe+0x12c/0x1a0
[   22.058470]  platform_probe+0x64/0xd0
[   22.062125]  really_probe+0x150/0x3a0
[   22.065779]  __driver_probe_device+0x10c/0x180
[   22.070215]  driver_probe_device+0x38/0xe0
[   22.074304]  __device_attach_driver+0x94/0x120
[   22.078740]  bus_for_each_drv+0x74/0xc0
[   22.082568]  __device_attach+0xf0/0x1a8
[   22.086396]  device_initial_probe+0x10/0x18
[   22.090572]  bus_probe_device+0x90/0x98
[   22.094400]  deferred_probe_work_func+0x9c/0xe8
[   22.098923]  process_one_work+0x1a0/0x2f0
[   22.102925]  worker_thread+0x210/0x3f8
[   22.106666]  kthread+0x10c/0x118
[   22.109887]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
```

And here's what my device tree looks like for the USB related items:

```
       aliases {
                ethernet0 = &gem3;
                i2c0 = &i2c0;
                i2c1 = &i2c1;
                mmc0 = &sdhci1;
                nvmem0 = &eeprom;
                rtc0 = &rtc;
                serial0 = &uart0;
                serial1 = &uart1;
                serial2 = &dcc;
                spi0 = &qspi;
                usb0 = &usb0;
                usb1 = &usb1;
        };
 
....
 
        pinctrl_usb0_default: usb0-default {
                mux {
                        groups = "usb0_0_grp";
                        function = "usb0";
                };
 
                conf {
                        groups = "usb0_0_grp";
                        slew-rate = <SLEW_RATE_SLOW>;
                        power-source = <IO_STANDARD_LVCMOS18>;
                };
 
                conf-rx {
                        pins = "MIO52", "MIO53", "MIO55";
                        bias-high-impedance;
                };
 
                conf-tx {
                        pins = "MIO54", "MIO56", "MIO57", "MIO58", "MIO59",
                               "MIO60", "MIO61", "MIO62", "MIO63";
                        bias-disable;
                };
        };
 
        pinctrl_usb1_default: usb1-default {
                mux {
                        groups = "usb1_0_grp";
                        function = "usb1";
                };
 
                conf {
                        groups = "usb1_0_grp";
                        slew-rate = <SLEW_RATE_SLOW>;
                        power-source = <IO_STANDARD_LVCMOS18>;
                };
 
                conf-rx {
                        pins = "MIO64", "MIO65", "MIO67";
                        bias-high-impedance;
                };
 
                conf-tx {
                        pins = "MIO66", "MIO68", "MIO69", "MIO70", "MIO71",
                               "MIO72", "MIO73", "MIO74", "MIO75";
                        bias-disable;
                };
        };
 
....
 
&usb0 {
        status = "okay";
        clocks = <0x3 0x20>;
        clock-names = "bus_clk";
};
 
&dwc3_0 {
        /delete-property/ phy-names ;
        /delete-property/ phys ;
        snps,refclk_fladj;
        snps,enable_guctl1_resume_quirk;
        snps,enable_guctl1_ipd_quirk;
        snps,xhci-stream-quirk;
        maximum-speed = "high-speed";
        snps,dis_u2_susphy_quirk;
        snps,dis_u3_susphy_quirk;
        snps,usb3_lpm_capable;
        status = "okay";
        dr_mode = "host";
};
 
&usb1 {
        status = "okay";
        clocks = <0x3 0x20>;
        clock-names = "bus_clk";
};
 
&dwc3_1 {
        /delete-property/ phy-names ;
        /delete-property/ phys ;
        snps,refclk_fladj;
        snps,enable_guctl1_resume_quirk;
        snps,enable_guctl1_ipd_quirk;
        snps,xhci-stream-quirk;
        maximum-speed = "high-speed";
        snps,dis_u2_susphy_quirk;
        snps,dis_u3_susphy_quirk;
        snps,usb3_lpm_capable;
        status = "okay";
        dr_mode = "host";
};
```

Comment: Does the device boot when disabling USB1 in the device tree? Are both USBs unconnected while booting?

Comment: Hi @Philippos thanks for the questions.  Yes to both.

Comment: And both USBs are symmetrical and you double checked the pins? Puh! Are you able to step through the boot process with a debugger? It's no fun to do `printf`-Debugging with kernel drivers.

Comment: @Philippos - Hmmmmm...  Not exactly sure what you mean by "symmetrical".  Agree printf debugging is no fun.  I need to learn how to debug the bootup process in a more sophisticated way.  I have a lot of experience with GDB in user space but none at all with the kernel bootup process.